# Netty closeFuture().sync().channel(); blocks rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

I am in the middle of learning Netty an started some tutorials using spring boot. My goal is to create an application which set up a tcp port for receiving messages and to present them over a rest api.

Most of the tutorials are saying that I should add something like this

```
serverChannel = serverBootstrap.bind(tcpPort).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync().channel();
```

to start netty.
When I do that, the rest services which I implemented are not working.
Now when I use the following code snippet to start the application:

```
serverChannel = serverBootstrap.bind(tcpPort).sync().channel();
```

everything seems to be working just fine. 
Could someone explain me what might cause this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first part start the server, 
1) binding it on a TCP port, 
2) wait for the server to be ready (socket is listening) 
3) and return the associated channel.

```
serverBootstrap.bind(tcpPort).sync().channel();
                 (1)           (2)       (3)
```

The second part is to wait for the main channel (listening socket) to shutdown (`closeFuture().sync()`) where `closeFuture` gives you the "future" on "close" operation (meaning shutdown of the server socket), and `sync` waiting for this future to be done. `channel()` gives you back the very same channel than first time, except it is now closed.

So you might find this code in various example because generally you start the server (bind) in the main thread or so, and then if you don't wait for something, the main thread will end up, giving your JVM finishing, and therefore your server to stop immediately after starting.

So in general, what we do is:

- start the server
- add in the pipeline the necessary handlers to handle your business logic (and the network protocol of course)
- then finish your main by waiting on closeFuture, such that, once in your business logic you get the order to shutdown, you close the main channel, and therefore your main thread is closing too.

See for instance [Shutdown netty programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032092/shutdown-netty-programmatically/28034689)

Comment: Mistake from myself: (2) is to wait for the main channel (listening socket) to be ready (not shutdown), then (3) gives back the corresponding channel. While `channel().closeFuture().sync()` closeFuture() gives the ChannelFuture of the shutdown of this channel, and then sync() wait for this channel to be closed, therefore shutdown...

Comment: why do we shutdown the channel? what is the main channel here?

Comment: The "main" channel is the "channel as listener through the socket", but not a "real channel" in the sens it is not connected (sub-channels will be connected channels, as sockets connected to the listener service, with, for each, a pipeline). It is important to stop listening to the adress/port before shutting down the application. So to resume: "main channel" is only a listener on address/port according to bind option, and you have to wait for it to be closed (no more listening, waiting for incomiing connections) to shutdown the application.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but I had same issue with my RestController not starting. Other answer helped solve it for me but here is full code for the Spring component.

```
import com.myserver.netty.handler.ClientInboundHandler;
import com.myserver.netty.handler.PacketDecoder;
import com.myserver.netty.handler.PacketEncoder;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

@Component
@Log4j2
public class NettyServer {

   private EventLoopGroup masters = new NioEventLoopGroup();
   private EventLoopGroup workers = new NioEventLoopGroup();

   private Channel mainChannel;

   @PostConstruct
   public void start() {
       try {
           ServerBootstrap bootstrap = init();
           mainChannel = bootstrap.bind(8484).sync().channel(); // save the main channel so we can cleanly close it when app is shutdown
           log.info("Netty Server started......");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   @PreDestroy
   public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
       log.info("Shutting down netty server");
       workers.shutdownGracefully().sync();
       masters.shutdownGracefully().sync();
       mainChannel.closeFuture().sync();
       log.info("Shutdown complete");
   }

   private ServerBootstrap init() {
       return new ServerBootstrap()
               .group(masters, workers)
               .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
               .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 5000)
               .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
               .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
               .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                   @Override
                   protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                       channel.pipeline()
                               .addLast(new PacketDecoder())
                               .addLast(new ClientInboundHandler())
                               .addLast(new PacketEncoder());
                   }
               });
   }

}
```